# Intent to open a live wallpaper in preview mode in android

Tags: android

I can open a livewallpaper chooser programatically in android with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
startActivity(intent);
```

but What to do if I want a livewallpaper app to be opened in preview mode? where there will be a button to set this as livewallpaper? Is there any way?